# Displaying groupings : CreditScore and Age against Churn

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I cannot seem to display these Customer Churn parameters:

I used this code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,7))
code.groupby(['CreditScore','Age']).count()['Exited'].unstack().plot(ax=ax)
ax.set_xlabel('Exited')
ax.set_ylabel('CreditScore')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-324d07c85ae1> in <module>
----> 1 fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,7))
      2 code.groupby(['CreditScore','Age']).count()['Exited'].unstack().plot(ax=ax)
      3 ax.set_xlabel('Exited')
      4 ax.set_ylabel('CreditScore')

NameError: name 'plt' is not defined
```

Comment: add `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` before the code.

Comment: I did try that and it still did not run properly ..